# Grails Domain Models Accessing the contents of db using SQL joins

Tags: sql, grails, model, inner-join

I have a model named Property

```
Class Property{
   String name
   RoomPreference roomPreference
}
```

Here RoomPreference is another model.

```
Class RoomPreference{
   String age
}
```

I stored data in these tables. I found that there is field 'ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID' in the Property table. 'ID' is a field in the RoomPreference table. 
For some task, I need to write an SQL query that joins these tables.

I wrote as,

```
 select * from 
 Property p, RoomPreference r
 where p.ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID=r.ID
```

But it gives an error saying that there is no field ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID in property table. What is the solution for joining these tables. I tried 'roomPreferenceId' also. But it gives an error.

Comment: If this is pure `sql`, then the table names should be hyphenated ex `Room_Preference` (unless you have mapped them). If it is `HQL`, then the field name is simply id. Can you show how you are executing this query ? As well as the mapping closure for each domain?

Comment: select p \
    from Property p, RoomPreference r \
    where \
    p.status = 'ACTIVE' \
    ${mask ? ' and within(p.position,:mask) = true ' : ''} \
    ${additionalConstraints} and p.ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID=r.id \
    ${additionalConstraintsForRoomPreference} \
    ${orderBy} \
      ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query is written as follows:

```
Select p 
 from Property p INNER JOIN p.roomPreference r
 where 
    ..........
```

In this way tables are joined in hibernate or HQL. INNER JOIN clause will join the tables, so there should not be 'p.room_preference_id=r.id' clause after 'where' clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to identify the column.So you need to add the below :
Add mapping in domain RoomPreference

```
class RoomPreference {
    Long id 
    ....
    static mapping = {
        id column:"ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID"

    }

}
```

Saw @Alidad comments now properly. Not sure are you are trying hsql or pure sql?
If you are using hql then as stated by @Alidad use id instead of ROOM_PREFERENCE_ID while making join.
static mapping property is always preferable as sometimes it saves you from unwanted  mapping errors.

Hope it helps.